# How can I start a GUI window from a QThread?

Tags: qt, user-interface, chat, qthread

I'm working on a chat program where the client is single-threaded but the server will start a new thread for each connected client.  I believe my client code is solid but the server has me bewildered.

Right now, I have a derived `QTcpSocket` class that looks for incoming connections and when it see's one, begins a new `QThread`.  When the `QThread` runs, it creates an instance of a `QMainWindow` (which is the chat window) and shows it.

```
void secureserver::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    securethread *thread = new securethread(socketDescriptor, this);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
}

void securethread::run()
{
    serverwindow myServerWindow;
    myServerWindow.setSocketDescriptor(mySocket);
    myServerWindow.show();
}
```

I've been getting errors to stderror like the following, and the `QMainWindow` never appears so chatting is impossible at this point.

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0xbf9e5358), parent's thread is QThread(0x98a54f0), current thread is securethread(0x99e9250)
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

My questions are:

- Do I need to make the `QThread` a parent of the `QMainWindow`?
- Am I going about this in the completely wrong way?
- Any other general ideas on why this isn't working as I expect it to
  or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm confused as to why your server has any GUI code at all. Seems to me that your clients should be the ones showing chat windows and the server should be purely a mechanism for passing messages from one client to the other.

Comment: The idea is that you have many clients, one server (one local IP address and port) but the server creates a new thread for each incoming connection.  The server can then communicate between one and only one client per window but it can send/receive in these new threads/windows simultaneously since they will be in their own threads.  I didn't design the specs for this program so I'm right with you asking why as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are going about this in the wrong way. GUIs, due to platform limits, are single threaded systems. You cannot create, change and manage GUI objects on different threads - everything must be done on one thread (normally, the GUI thread).

Qt has two mechanisms for dealing with worker threads and the GUI: **queued** signals and slots, and the QCoreApplication::postEvent() handler.

More details are in the comprehensive Qt threading document: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html

Comment: Hmm, do you have any suggestions for opening a new window for each incoming client connection then?
This is a requirement for the project that the server be multi-threaded and have a new chat window pop-up for each client attempting to chat so that multiple clients can communicate with the server simultaneously.

Comment: @JLaw: Threads can process I/O and messages, but all GUI activity needs to be done on one thread. You should communicate to the UI using a queued signal/slot mechanism, not mixing sever code and UI code.

Comment: That makes sense, I can use signals and slots then.  The only thing I'm still left wondering about is that I need to have a separate window pop-up for each client.  Can I still use my incomingConnection function to create a new instance of a GUI window and a thread and use signals/slots between that thread and window?

Comment: @JLaw: No, you cannot create Windows (or do any interaction with GUI anything) in a Thread that is not the GUI thread. Your GUI needs to be responsible for managing the windows, not the server thread.